# What is the Excel equivalent of Find & Replace catch-all "*" in libreoffice calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, I am trying to find and replace all characters after a blank space to delete, and similarly to find and replace all characters before a blank space to delete, but the "*" is not recognized as in Excel.

What is the proper syntax for the catch-all Excel character "*" in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Do you want only the character following the space to be deleted or both the space and the character to be deleted??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Alternative search extension](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer)

After installation you could invoke dialog with Ctrl+H
Make sure that "Regular expression" in "More options" is checked.

For your particular case regexp will be

```
.*\s
```

"." matches all characters (like * in Excel)

".*" matches all number of characters (even if there is none of them)

and "\s" matches any (one) whitespace

If you want to preserve space, type space in "Replace with" filed

Also, take a look at this:
[image]

*Note: I would highly recommend you to read the book on regular expressions, if you want to complete complex tasks with them, because they are a lot more powerfull, than usual "*?" masks. Also, you can use them in formulas.*